# How to enter the `Virtual-CD/DVD` in MaxDOS?

Tags: windows, ms-dos

In the iDRAC you see I have loaded the `Samsung_SSD_...iso` in the `Virtual-CD/DVD`:

[image]

but in the MaxDOS, how can I enter the `Samsung_SSD...iso` for check the content? 
[image]

you see the snapshot, I don't know how to enter the `Virtual-CD/DVD`.